# command for removing a specific over lay item

Tags: android

what is The command for removing specific overlay item ?
if here is my code of the added items

```
public void addOverLays(){
String [] coordinates = {"30.084262490272522","31.33625864982605" ,"30.084123015403748", "51.5002" , "-0.1262","31.337149143218994"};
double lat = 30.084262490272522, lat2 = 51.5002,lat3=29.987091422080994;
double log = 31.33625864982605, log2 = -0.1262,log3=31.43909454345703;

p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (log * 1E6));
p2 = new GeoPoint( (int) (lat2 * 1e6), (int) (log2 * 1e6));
p3=new GeoPoint( (int) (lat3 * 1e6), (int) (log3 * 1e6));
mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ballon);
drawable2 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ballon);
drawable3 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ballon);

itemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);
itemizedOverlay2 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable2,this);        
itemizedOverlay3 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable3,this);    
OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, "Cairo", " over1");
OverlayItem over2 = new OverlayItem(p2, "ulm", "over2");
OverlayItem over3 = new OverlayItem(p3, "offff", "over3");

itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

itemizedOverlay2.addOverlay(over2);
mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay2);

itemizedOverlay3.addOverlay(over3);
mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace add() with remove():

```
mapView.getOverlays().remove(<putYourOverlayHere>);
mapView.invalidate();
```

Comment: can i do this under a specific condition ?! when my gps current location is == the overlay item ?
mapView.getOverlays().remove(<putYourOverlayHere>); // is  the overlayItem ?

Comment: Why not? See my answer to your other question. Compare both coordinates (GPS and spot) and if your condition is true remove that OverlayItem.